# What percentage of volcanic energy is of solar origin?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, geophysics

As I understand, the earth is in thermal equilibrium with solar irradiation, terrestrial radiation and nuclear decay processes happening inside the earth:

(Energy from nuclear decay) + (Solar Energy impinging on earth) = (Solar energy reflected by earth) + (Geothermal energy radiated from earth)

Now if there is a spike in geothermal energy radiated from earth, such as when a volcano breaks out, this equilibrium is disrupted: The earth cools down ever so slightly, and for a while, some more solar energy will be absorbed by earth due to the increased temperature gradient. Also, a little less of the energy from nuclear decay will be emitted from earth, and instead will be used for heating earth up for a while, until the old equilibrium is reestablished.

My question is: What percentage of that energy replenishment comes from the sun - and what comes from the earth?

My guess would be that the ratio of terrestrial contribution to solar contribution is:

(Power of nuclear decay inside earth)/(Power of solar radiation impinging on earth).

I have no idea how to estimate the nominator. The denominator is well known.
However, I would be surprised if the earth is (locally) a more powerful energy source than the sun, so it seems that volcanos mostly spout solar energy... am I missing something?

By the way, [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563971/is-geothermal-energy-ultimately-derived-from-solar-energy) previous question does not give any consideration to my reasoning here.

Comment: You're missing a couple important additional sources of energy: stored energy (specific heat) and tidal energy (due to gravitational forces of other solar system objects, mostly the sun and moon). These will pretty well require to reformulate your equations, and render the question unanswerable in it's present form.

Comment: I think tidal forces can be neglected. As for the primordial energy (specific heat): If my assumption holds that the earth is in thermal equilibrium, then that energy should have dissipated by now.

Comment: Tidal forces are the primary source of heating on some planetary bodies, so cannot be neglected. And the earth will not be in thermal equilibrium until the core is much colder, and definately colder than it's surface, if the primary source of heat is solar radiation.

Comment: I think I used the wrong word: I meant "thermodynamic" equilibrium, not thermal equilibrium.

Comment: OK. But it's still true that specifc heat content of the earth and tidal heat generation are also heat inputs to the thermodynamic model. Not just solar irradiation, natural fission, and planetary radiation.